# MAPE over 100% after normalization of dataset

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, normalization, forecasting

I try to forecast power demand for next 24 hours. Years 2017 and 2018 are my training set, 2019 is test set. I use multistep vanilla LSTM . In first step I used original data with any preparation and I get MAPE score about 7,5%. Then I read some article about doing the same thing in Matlab and they use to types of normalization of dataset:
First one
$$
P_n(d,h)=\frac{P(d,h)}{max_⁡P}
$$
Second one
$$
P_n(d,h)=\frac{((P(d,h)-mean(P(d)))}{std(P(d))}
$$
When I use first one Make drop to 3,5% and in article second one gets even better scores. But when I use it my forecast was very wrong with MAPE 130% and very big errors. I don't find in internet anyone with the same problem. I tried using MinMax scaler but MAPE was around 20%. I think it have something with very small values because when modified second normalization to have every value greater than zero MAPE drop to 78%.
this is my neural network

```
def build_model(train, n_input):
    # prepare data
    train_x, train_y = to_supervised(train, n_input)
    # define parameters
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 2, 100, 72
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(400, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_outputs))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='RMSprop')
    # fit network
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    return model
```

this is link to my Colab [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RZ5xxcX1pqM5Fp7kMuuxTje7_s3UGSh7)

this is normalization

```
#first one
load_norm=data['load'].max()
data2=data.copy()/data['load'].max()
```

```
#second one
import datetime 
def no_trend(x):
  mean=x.mean()
  std=x.std()
  return (x-mean)/std
def no_trend_transform(data):
  index_range=data.copy()
  index_range=index_range.resample('D').mean()
  index_range.reset_index(inplace=True)
  index_range['index']=index_range['index'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
  for i in index_range['index']:
    data[i]=no_trend(data[i])
  return data.dropna()
data2=no_trend_transform(data.copy())
```

Dataset [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rvYNrwRcXnHKK0yIhAAhr4s2DMEoZuIw/view?usp=sharing)

Do you have any idea what is a problem? I tried this that a set with other types of LSTM and MLP and I have the same problem.